# how do I add text to a button?

Tags: ms-access

This should have a really obvious answer but I can't figure it out...

I've made a button in Access 2007 that takes the user to a form (and other buttons that do other things). I've made the button's background an image so that I could have a gradient-style button but I'd also like to have text on top of this. There is text on the button but it gets hidden either because it's just a name given to the button for VB or because the gradient image is being place on top of it...

any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Access 2010, and Access 2007 supports both text and graphics on buttons.

Eg note the top buttons:

[image]

or simply this:

[image]

I do believe that transparency in 2010 is better supported, and the options for buttons in 2010 does include shadow and gradient options:

Eg:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you did set picture as button background. Might be do you mean that you have two independent controls, an image and a button. In this case right click on the image and Position / Send to back. Back style of the button should be Transparent, but Transparent property should be set "No".

Comment: I meant a command button - it gives you the option to select a background image for the button in the wizard. If there's no way of putting text on top of this, I'll use your idea and put an image under a transparent button.